# I'm trying to create a button that when I pres it will add a card.in the Dialog lines have a button I need it to return the CardMedia down

Tags: reactjs

What i want is the second button in the Dialog I want to return the CardMedia down so.
I', doing a project whit a team is to create a class for student. my job is to create a button that have a popup with title and description when I put the ifo and click create it's should make a card with the title and description.

````
import React,{ useState }from 'react'
import {Card,CardActions,CardContent,CardMedia,Button,Typography, Grid} from '@mui/material';
import image from '../images/student.jpg'
import image1 from '../images/student1.jpeg'
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Dialog from '@mui/material/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@mui/material/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@mui/material/DialogContent';
import DialogTitle from '@mui/material/DialogTitle';
import '../styles/dashboard.css';


function Dashboard() {
const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
};
const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
}


    return (
        <div>
            {/** this is the dashboard image  */}
            <img src={image} alt="" className="first-image"/>
        
            {/**THIS THE POPUP FOR CREATING A CLASS */}
        <Grid>
            <Grid item xs={3} align='center'>
              <Button variant="outlined" sx={{ width:250, height:262, fontSize: 35}} onClick={handleClickOpen}> + </Button>
            </Grid> 
        </Grid>
              <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
                <DialogTitle>Creating a class!</DialogTitle>
                <DialogContent>
                <TextField margin="dense" id="discription" label="Title" type="discription" fullWidth variant="filled"/>
                <TextField
                  id="outlined-multiline-static"
                  label="Discription"
                  multiline
                  rows={5}
                  fullWidth variant="filled"
         />
                 
                  {/**THIS IS THE BUTTONS that will retun a card */}
                </DialogContent>
                <DialogActions>
                  <Button onClick={handleClose}>Cancel</Button>
                  <Button onClick={handleClose}>Create</Button> 
                </DialogActions>
              </Dialog>
              <br/>

              <Grid container spacing={10} sx={{p: 5}}>
    <Grid item xs={3} align='center'>
        {/**this is the card */}
            <Card variant='outlined'>
                <CardMedia
                    component="img"
                    alt="green iguana"
                    height="140"
                    image={image1}
                />
                <CardContent>
                    <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">Are you ready for some new Arabic words!</Typography>
                </CardContent>
                <CardActions>
                    <Button variant="contained">Go to</Button>
                </CardActions>
            </Card>
    </Grid>
    </Grid>



        </div>
        )}

export default Dashboard;```
````

Comment: Maintain a state which will be initially an empty array. When you click on create button push an object which will contain the title and description into the array. Then render that.

Comment: I try it but didn't work maybe I do it in the wrong way if you can show me how if you don't mind